# spawn or system from racket

Tags: scheme, posix, racket

im trying to write a script for my system that populates static html files from a directory structure.

id prefer to use racket for the task but am having diffaculty finding a few key features, most importantly the ability to spawn a subprocess, such as the C call "system".

what is the easiest way to call the command line, and capture output, from inside of racket.

Comment: Just search the documentation: http://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html?q=system

Comment: thanka for pointing me in the right direction, "system" is a muddy term for search engines, so many results

Comment: For a general search engine, definitely. But language specific documentation can narrow them enough.

Comment: To be fair to @FireCrow, a lot of languages are lacking good documentation and documentation search engines. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are in fact two functions that work vary similar to system in C, they are: [`system`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/subprocess.html?q=system#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fsystem..rkt%29._system%29%29) and [`system*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/subprocess.html?q=system#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fsystem..rkt%29._system*%29%29). (There are other ways of spawning off subprocesses, but these two are the simplest and work very similar to many other languages.

Of the two, `system` is the easier one, and takes in the command you want to run as a string. That way you can do things such as:

```
(system "ls -l")
```

While it is a little more complicated to use, I like `system*` a bit better, as it takes in the arguments as a list, which means you can more easily play with them in Racket proper.

```
(system* (find-executable-path "ls") "-l")
```

Now, you can do things such as changing the input and output ports of the command you are running, and even change the current working directory via Racket's [parameters](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/parameterize.html?q=find-executable-path#%28tech._parameter%29). Specifically, you want `current-directory`, `current-input-port`, and `current-output-port`.

You can also use several `with-` functions to more conveniently change the input and output ports.

Putting it all together, I can, for example, save the results of running `ls -l` as a string with the following code. (Note that there are [better ways to get the contents of your root directory](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._directory-list%29%29) in Racket, this is just an example of using Racket for shell scripting.)

```
(parameterize ([current-directory "/"])
  (with-output-to-string
      (λ ()
        (system* (find-executable-path "ls") "-l"))))
```